# XSLT get nth position of an element inside the whole document

Tags: xml, xslt, position

This is my xml:

```xml
<body>
    <p>
        dumy text dumy text dumy text dumy text
        <div>
            dumy text dumy text dumy text dumy text
            <note>LOREM</note>
            dumy text dumy text dumy text dumy text
        </div>
        <note>IPSUM</note>
    </p>
    <p>
        dumy text dumy text dumy text dumy text
        <note>DOLOR</note>
        dumy text dumy text dumy text dumy text
    </p>
        dumy text dumy text dumy text dumy text
        <note>SIT</note>
    <div>
        <note>AMET</note>
    </div>
        dumy text dumy text dumy text dumy text
</body>
```

The output should be:

```html
<body>
    <p>
        dumy text dumy text dumy text dumy text
        <div>
            dumy text dumy text dumy text dumy text
            <note rank="note1">1. LOREM</note>
            dumy text dumy text dumy text dumy text
        </div>
        <note rank="note2">2. IPSUM</note>
    </p>
    <p>
        dumy text dumy text dumy text dumy text
        <note rank="note3">3. DOLOR</note>
        dumy text dumy text dumy text dumy text
    </p>
        dumy text dumy text dumy text dumy text
        <note rank="note4">4. SIT</note>
    <div>
        <note rank="note5">5. AMET</note>
    </div>
        dumy text dumy text dumy text dumy text
</body>
```

I tried the following xslt:

```xml
    <xsl:template match="*/note">
        <xsl:value-of select="count(ancestor::root/preceding-sibling::root)+1" />
    <xsl:apply-templates />
```

But the number is not incremented at each new `<note>`. They are all numbered 1.

So, how to get all `<note>` numbered according to their position inside the document, knowing they don’t necessary share the same ancestor?

##### Edit

I add the number position inside an attribute’s value.

Comment: The accepted solution is better, but an alternative would be to do `count(preceding::note)+1`. Your solution makes no sense, since there are no `root` elements in the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="note">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:number level="any" format="1. "/>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Ow… yes it work fine. Just one last question, how to store the same number in an attribute value as I showed in my edit?

Comment: Put it in a variable first, then take it from there to both locations.